# Toyota Auris Hybrid sometimes is reluctant to enter READY mode

Tags: toyota, starting, hybrid

I've bought a Toyota Auris Hybrid 2011 in June last year. I've got no issues until November, when for the first time it didn't want to start. For next few weeks the issue didn't come up, so I thought I've accidentally activated steering wheel block or something similar. However, it appeared a month after, and yesterday.

I've identified the problem a bit more. It had happened until now only after a few days the car was idle. Normally the READY lamp goes on a few seconds after pressing start, but when the issue happens, it doesn't go on even after 10 seconds. However, I've also found a solution. Turn car off, open and close doors and try again. After a few times it will start, and drive without any problem.

What can cause such strange behavior?

Comment: any warning lights? security? key fob missing?

Comment: @Ben nothing extraordinary, after starting the car with non-ready mode I have a standard set of all warning lights, but it's the same when I consiously start that mode... Once it goes ready, there are no warnings...

Comment: How many miles (or KM) are on the car? While seven years old isn't ancient for a hybrid battery, it's not unheard of for a cell to start going bad. Also, have you cleaned out the battery fan ventilation system since you bought it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the engine is started after the hybrid system has been on for bit less than 10 seconds. Before that, the computers boot up using the 12V battery, not using the hybrid battery. Also, the hybrid battery will probably last for 20 years, whereas the lead-acid 12V battery will need to be replaced after about 5-10 years. So, I think the answerer here has a point.

Comment: @juhist - Eh, don't count on a hybrid battery lasting for 20 years. They offer replacements for Toyota's with less than 10 year on them ... should tell you something.

Comment: @juhist - I take that back, you can purchase a remanned Dorman Battery Pack for a 2016 Camry off of RockAuto.

Comment: Oh, that's certainly contrary to what I have understood. But anyway, my main point about hybrid battery still stands, that it would cause a faulty engine start and/or lack of electric propulsion power, not a faulty hybrid system start (the hybrid system starts before the engine starts using the 12V battery).

Comment: @juhist I'm confused about you mentioning 12V battery. I wasn't aware hybrids have them - what for? I've called the garage where I've bought it, if I've understood them well their answer was the car has only hybrid batteries... 
Is there any explanation why it doesn't start at first time but starts after a few tries?

Comment: @DanubianSailor The answers to this question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21277/can-i-jumpstart-a-non-hybrid-car-from-a-hybrid-or-full-electric-car/21280 ...explain why there is a 12V battery on hybrids as well.

Comment: @juhist if I have understood this answer correctly, this 12V battery has nothing to do with starting electric motor, and lights and computer are starting immediately. The hybrid battery is also charged and have no issue... The mechanic from the garage have suggested that maybe I've pressed brakes too gently, I'll see what the future brings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check on this link, similar issue and it is due to bad 12V battery
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvTWSDuUPUs

Comment: I have faced same issue. after replace the start battery it is fixed

Comment: Confirmed, I haven't got the hybrids need the 12V battery in the same way the old-timers do. The service asserted me the battery is OK, and once it died completely I've finally learned the hard way that your answer is perfectly correct.